# May a woman pray in front of a man if he is using a sutrah?

Tags: salat, men-women

Ordinarily, women should not pray in front of men:

> The best rows for men are the first rows, and the worst ones the last ones, and the best rows for women are the last ones and the worst ones for them are the first ones. -- [Sahih Muslim 440](https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/147-148)

I'm wondering if a [sutrah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutrah) placed in between could make this permissible.

> A sutrah is an object used by a person performing salat as a barrier between himself and one passing in front of him.

**Question**: May a woman pray in front of a man if he is using a sutrah?

Comment: Note a sutrah can be as simple and small as a shoe, a sword or peace of wood...